# How to log testcontainers' logs when using Quarkus and JUnit Platform with Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, quarkus, junit5, testcontainers

I have written some BDD tests using Quarkus (3.2.9.Final), with JUnit Platform to launch Cucumber (7.15.0).

In my tests, I do not start Quarkus, but instead I launch several Testcontainers for the dependencies and even for the application under test. Then, I call an endpoint and assert the reply.

By itself, the tests are working, and Cucumber logs the usual success or failure message (the next one is just an example):

```
Running hellocucumber.RunCucumberTest
Feature: Is it Friday yet?
  Everybody wants to know when it's Friday

  Scenario: Sunday isn't Friday        # hellocucumber/is_it_friday_yet.feature:4
    Given today is Sunday              # Stepdefs.today_is_Sunday()
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet # Stepdefs.i_ask_whether_it_s_Friday_yet()
    Then I should be told "Nope"       # Stepdefs.i_should_be_told(String)

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
0m0.255s
```

However, I have been unable to log from the various Testcontainers. They just do not log anything at all.

I have tried to set the properties in Quarkus, lower the global level, setting `followOutput()` on the containers and/or `withLogConsumer()`, but I just could not get live logs from Testcontainers. Something that could be useful to understand what is going on; for example, if it is downloading them, or what each container is logging in general.

Do you have any suggestion that I can try?